# Dojo EnhancedGrid: How can I make particular cell editable not the entire column

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

Lets say Grid has 10 rows and I want to make Cell (9th row of col2 field) editable. Could you please give me any solution for this?

Here is my Grid

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: store,
    autoWidth: true,
    structure: [
        { name: "Number", field: "col1", width: "84px", editable: false},
        { name: "Description", field: "col2", width: "84px", editable: false },
        { name: "Stock", field: "col3", width: "84px", editable: false }
    ]
}, "grid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using canEdit function as below. Below example shows how not to make first cell non-editable.

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: store,
    autoWidth: true,
    structure: [
        { name: "Number", field: "col1", width: "84px", editable: false},
        { name: "Description", field: "col2", width: "84px", editable: false },
        { name: "Stock", field: "col3", width: "84px", editable: false }
    ],
 canEdit: function (inCell, inRowIndex) {
            if (inRowIndex && inCell.index === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return this._canEdit;
        }
}, "grid");
```